# 'Weird' Indexing In The MILP Literature

Tags: operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

Fairly new to MILP. I posted this question as [an issue](https://github.com/Gurobi/modeling-examples/issues/3) on the Gurobi examples repo too, but it might be more appropriate to ask it here.

NOTE: Since I "need at least 10 reputation to post images" , the images won't render, but they **are** available on the github issue linked above and I have linked to the urls (sorry).

I was following [this great example](https://gurobi.github.io/modeling-examples/technician_routing_scheduling/technician_routing_scheduling.html) from Gurobi.

In the model formulation, we have:
[link to image of formulation]https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19332617/108038384-70a65200-7043-11eb-9fbd-1eb9005240b6.png

I see that we have:
*d∈D={n+1,n+2,...,n+m}: Index and set of depots (service centers), where m is the number of depots.*
I am confused as to how there can be n+m depots.
I am also confused as to why the set starts from n+1 instead of 1. In the example there are two depots, not 9 i.e 2+7.

I have run into something similar when studying the literature ([Ramkumar et al 2012](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257790329_Mixed_integer_linear_programming_model_for_multi-commodity_multi-depot_inventory_routing_problem), their formulation also has confusing indices for the number of depots:
[link to image of Ramkumar formulation](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19332617/108038968-25407380-7044-11eb-858e-f40fdfe7e048.png)
)

Edit: Indeed, the paper referenced in the notebook also notes "(1,..,n+m) where the m depots are represented by n+1,...,n+m" but does not state their reasoning for doing so. (S. Salhi, A. Imran, N. A. Wassan. The multi-depot vehicle routing problem with heterogeneous vehicle fleet: Formulation and a variable neighborhood search implementation. Computers & Operations Research 52 (2014) 315-325.)

Edit 2: However, in the [Supply Network I](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zh-jHGnEJaEg8TU98eKEDnfCdbcgLXJ7)  example, we have something that makes more sense (to me).:
[link to Supply Network formulation image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19332617/108043134-64bd8e80-7049-11eb-9449-f0d31fd72d20.png)

Here there is no (n+1...n+m) indexing.

Any enlightenment on this indexing and why it used would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Meaning of MILP ?

Comment: Mixed integer linear programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that there are $n+m$ nodes in total, with $n$ of one type (customer) and $m$ of the other type (depot).  The first $n$ are customers $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and the last $m$ are depots $\{n+1,\dots,n+m\}$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question @RobPratt. That makes perfect sense. Is there a reason why it is sometimes not used (like in the Supply Network example)? Although, I do see Cities =Factories∪Depots∪Customers. Maybe they just didn't write the indexing explicitly.

Comment: In the supply network example, there is no collision of names to be avoided. But in the routing example, if you name the customers $1,\dots,n$ and the depots $1,\dots,m$, the union would not make sense.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks again!